# Github page make my .jpg image become a special image? (png image is normal)

Tags: github-pages

Github page show image only .png work but no .jpg and .gif.
So I don't think it is my path problem,because my .png image is show.
Moreover,I get jpg become a special file but not 404 page.

For Example:

I can get png image by https://alwxkxk.github.io/blog/blog_images/empty-list.png
[image]

But I get jpg image become a special image.

https://alwxkxk.github.io/blog/blog_images/005BIQVbgy1fuo1rwsry0j30t3097jtr.jpg

[image]

This picture in github is right: https://github.com/alwxkxk/blog/blob/gh-pages/blog_images/005BIQVbgy1fuo1rwsry0j30t3097jtr.jpg

[image]

How to debug this problem?

github page project url: https://github.com/alwxkxk/blog/tree/gh-pages

page :https://alwxkxk.github.io/blog/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INCORRECT ANSWER:

Incorrectly generated url to your image. Try to use `.` before relative path `![](./blog/blog_images/005BIQVbgy1fuo1rwsry0j30t3097jtr.jpg)`.

See [answer](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/1757#issuecomment-643437143) for more details.

EDIT:

Reason why your jpg files are not shown is because they are **Stored with Git LFS**. See [issue](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1342) - according to it "GitHub Pages doesn't support Git LFS".

There is [workaround](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1342#issuecomment-334317440) - do not use relative path, use absolute path with `?raw=true`. Example: `https://github.com/alwxkxk/blog/blob/gh-pages/blog_images/005BIQVbgy1fuo1rwsry0j30t3097jtr.jpg?raw=true`

Comment: I have changed to relative path,but still only show .png image but not .jpg.